# If condition to match a string followed by 4 digit number

Tags: bash, shell

I want to check a particular string condition from a variable I have  entered with if condition

```
read -p "name: " name
if [$name -eq HQ-JQK-any 4 digit number]
then
echo "entered pattern is correct"
else
echo "entered pattern is incorrect"
fi
```

entered string `HQ-JQK` is always permanent i want to check the numbers from `1000-9999`

Comment: `if` is not a loop.

Comment: Side notes: Spaces *matter* -- `if [$name ...` will treat the value of `$name` as part of the command name (i.e. it'll be looking for a command named `[HQ-JQK-1234`), but `[ $name ...` might work. Or not, because under some circumstances the variable's value will be parsed weirdly unless you double-quote it, like `[ "$name" ...`. Finally, inside a `[ ]` type test expression, `-EQ` tests for *numeric* equality, not string comparison let alone pattern matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`case` statement](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-case):

```
read -p "name: " name
case "$name" in
    HQ-JQK-[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])
        echo "entered pattern is correct";;
    *)
        echo "entered pattern is incorrect";;
esac
```

Comment: also one thing if the pattern is incorrect script should stop and if the pattern is correct it should execute lines after esac .

Comment: @sysadmincrispy : It's up to you to just `exit 1` after the error message!

Comment: @melpomene : Style question: Is there a particuar reason why you solved this with `case ... esac` instead of `if [[ .... ]] .. fi`?

Comment: @user1934428 `[[` confuses and scares me. Also, it uses `=` for pattern matching, which is counterintuitive.

Comment: You are scared by brackets??? For pattern matching, do a `==` if you don't like `=`.

Comment: @user1934428 How is `==` better than `=`? It still looks like an equality test.

Comment: Since I know that matching by wildcard expansion is done, it doesn't look like equality to me. Just thought that if you have an aversion against a single equal sign, maybe a double one would look better to you. I mean: We **know** the language, and we **know** what the operators are doing. Not wanting to use a feature only for simple aesthetical reasons is not a path I would follow.

Comment: @user1934428 Not using features for aesthetic reasons is something we do all the time. As for knowing things: I know how `[` works (and `=` does mean equality there) and I don't know how `[[` works. It is weird and has special parsing rules.

Comment: @melpomene : Well, `[[` is internal syntax, not a "command". I find that the special parsing rules (which usually avoid the need for quoting a variable) make it easier to use. But I agree that, in the end, it is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use regex?

```
pattern='HQ-JQK-[1-9]([0-9]{3})'

read -r -p "name: " name
if [[ $name =~ $pattern ]]; then
   echo "entered pattern is correct"
else
   echo "entered pattern is incorrect"
fi
```

Comment: also one thing if the pattern is incorrect script should stop and if the pattern is correct it should execute lines after fi